# Polynomial of 4th degree

Tags: polynomials

I would like to ask if someone could help me with the following equation.
\begin{equation}
x^4+ax^3+(a+b)x^2+2bx+b=0
\end{equation}
Could you first solve in general then $a=11$ and $b=28$.
I get it to this form but I stuck.
\begin{equation}
1+a\left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)+b\left(\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^3}+\frac{1}{x^3}+\frac{1}{x^4}\right) = 0
\end{equation}
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you believe that there will be a nice solution?  There does exist a [generalized solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots) but hardly anyone ever uses or learns it beyond learning of its existence.

Comment: For the special case of $a=11,b=28$ and the problem having been assigned by a teacher or a textbook, you could pray that one or more of the roots would be a small negative integer such as $-1$ or $-2$ (*cough cough*) noting that any real roots would have to be negative, and if you are correct then you could perform long division, reducing this to a cubic or a quadratic and continue from there with more standard approaches.

Comment: $u = \left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$, so the plynomial looks like this $1+au+b\left(\frac{u}{x}+\frac{u}{x^2}\right) = 0$, but i dont know how to continue.

Comment: Assume $x \ne -1$, you can rewrite your equation as $$x^4 + ax^2(x+1)+b(x+1)^2 = 0 \iff \left(\frac{x^2}{x+1}\right)^2 + a\left(\frac{x^2}{x+1}\right) + b = 0$$

Comment: Could you explain to me? Please.

Comment: How do you come up with $x^4+ax^2(x+1)+b(x+1)^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polynomial equation for $(a, b)=(11,28)$ is given by
$$
x^4+11x^3+39x^2+56x+28=(x^2 + 7x + 7)(x + 2)^2=0.
$$
"How do we come up wit this layout"? By the rational root test, we find the factor $x-2$ twice, and dividing gives the factor $x^2+7x+7$. Hence the roots are $x=-2,-2,\frac{\sqrt{21}-7}{2},\frac{-\sqrt{21}-7}{2}$.

In general, the polynomial will not have any integral roots. A good example is the case $(a, b)=(1,1)$, where the polynomial
$$
x^4+x^3+2x^2+2x+1
$$
is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$. It has no real root at all.

Comment: Yes, but how you came up with this layout?

Comment: The layout is [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Or are you referring to the factorization? This is the rational root test.

Comment: @DietrichBurde that is obviously not what he was referring to by layout.  He was talking about the approach.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there !

$$1+a\left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)+b\left(\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^3}+\frac{1}{x^3}+\frac{1}{x^4}\right) = 0$$
$$1+a\left(\frac{x+1}{x^2}\right)+b\left(\frac{x+1}{x^3}+\frac{x+1}{x^4}\right) = 0$$
$$1+a\left(\frac{x+1}{x^2}\right)+b\left(\frac{x+1}{x^2}\right)^2 = 0$$

Comment: I am not sure it is obvious how did get the first equation.

Comment: This is from OP.  x^4 + a*(x^3+x^2) + b*(x^2 + 2x + 1) = 0. Divide it by x^4.

Comment: Thanks. How to go on to find $x$?

Comment: After above quadratic solved, we have 2 roots, say r1, r2.  Solved 2 more quadratics, r1*x^2 = x+1, r2*x^2 = x+1, and we have all 4 roots.  Note: r1, r2 might be complex.  It is harder to solve, but you only need to solve 1, and doubled the roots with complex conjugates.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation but the last equation would be transformed to a degree 4 equation, which is not easier to solve than the original.